# Select 2 columns from table, query in one

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, sqlite

In android I wrote this code:

```
public Trap getCloseTrap() 
    {   
        SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();      
        Cursor cur = db.query(TRAP_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT+" ASC LIMIT 1");
        Trap closeTrap = readFromCursor(cur);
        cur.close();
        return closeTrap;
    }
```

In objective-c I tried to do something similar, this way:

```
- (Traps*)getCloseTrap
{
    Traps *aTrap = [[Traps alloc] init];
    // SELECT * FROM traps_table ORDER BY dist_to_close_point ASC LIMIT 1
    NSString *sqlStatment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ ORDER BY %@ ASC LIMIT 1", TRAP_TABLE, DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT];
    FMResultSet *query = [db executeQuery:sqlStatment];
    while ([query next]) {
        int trapID = [query intForColumn:ID];
        aTrap = [self getTrap_trapID:trapID];
    }
    return aTrap;
}
```

I didn't tested it yet but I know I've something wrong in here with my objective-c code.

**EDIT:**

Fixed my code plus using FMDB now.

Comment: Do you know what "LIMIT 1" in your query means?

Comment: Get no more then 1 row as result.

Comment: So, want to do in android? right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're missing `ORDER BY <column_name>` from the SQL. In Android, the query builder adds `ORDER BY` for you but with raw SQL you'll have to do it yourself.
2. `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` compiles the SQL but doesn't run it. Use `sqlite3_step()` to run the compiled query. This is the same as cursor `moveTo...()` in Android.

Comment: OK, then how can I put this in code? What I want is asc sorting to 'dist_to_close_point' and then get the 'trapID'. I'm a little bit confused.